# Unable to add window token android.os.BinderProxy@4250d6d8 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

One user sent me this crash report yesterday:

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4250d6d8 is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:698)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:552)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:833)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So i searched and it is said that the solution is to change `this` to `Activity.this` 
But this solution didnt work even if i use the following code:

```
//Oncreate Method.....

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

         AlertDialog.Builder alertd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

         alertd.setMessage("StackOverflow");

         alertd.setTitle("Example");

         AlertDialog alertd2 = alertd.create();

         alertd2.show();
        }

                      });
```

Should i change something?

Comment: Where are you running this? Show some more code.

Comment: Add the full onCreate method, with the class also.

Comment: If possible add the full activity code

Comment: Activity there is nothing to do with alertdialog

Comment: Click on button. Then before Alert is appeared, quickly press BACK button of device twice. That will cause this error. Actually i don't know an exact solution yet.

Answer (score 16):

Finally, i found the solution. Problem is that, your alert tries to show, although your activity is finished.

So what you should do is to check if activity is finishing before showing alert. For this purpose  **isFinishing()**  method is defined within Activity class.

Here is what you shoul do:

```
 if(!isFinishing())
 {
     alert.show();
 }
```

Have fun.